# Approximating a compact linear operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $T:H\rightarrow H$ is a compact linear operator on infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$, and let $\{x_n\}$ be an orthonormal set of eigenvectors of $T^*T$. I want to show $\| T-S_N\|\rightarrow 0$ in operator norm where $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,x_n \rangle T(x_n)$ and $S_Nx=\sum_{n=1}^N \langle x,x_n\rangle T(x_n)$. I've so far done the following.

Take $x\in H$.
$$ 0\leq\|Tx-S_Nx\|=\| \langle x,x_{N+1}\rangle Tx_{N+1} + \langle x,x_{N+2}\rangle Tx_{N+2} + \cdots \| $$
$$ \leq \| \langle x,x_{N+1}\rangle Tx_{N+1} \| +\| \langle x,x_{N+2}\rangle Tx_{N+2} \| + \cdots  $$
$$ \leq  | \langle x,x_{N+1}\rangle| \| T \| \|x_{N+1} \| + |\langle x,x_{N+2}\rangle | \| T \| \| x_{N+2} \| + \cdots  $$
$$ =  | \langle x,x_{N+1}\rangle| \| T \|   + |\langle x,x_{N+2}\rangle | \| T \|   + \cdots  $$
$$ \leq \|x\| \| x_{N+1}\| \| T \|   + \|x\| \| x_{N+2}\| \| T \|   + \cdots  $$
$$ = \|x\| \| T \| + \|x\| \| T \|   + \cdots  $$
So,

$$ 0\leq \frac{\|Tx-S_Nx\|}{\|x\|} \leq \|T\|$$
and hence
$$ 0\leq \|T -S_N \|  \leq \|T\|$$

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $T^*Tx_n=\lambda_nx_n$. We may assume, as $T$ is compact and positive, that $\lambda_n\searrow0$.

You have 
\begin{align}
\|Tx-S_Nx\|^2&=\left\|\sum_{n>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle\,Tx_n \right\|^2 \\ \ \\
&=\left\langle \sum_{n>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle\,Tx_n,\sum_{n>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle\,Tx_n\right\rangle\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{n>N}\sum_{m>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle \overline{\langle x,x_m\rangle}\,\langle Tx_n,Tx_m\rangle\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{n>N}\sum_{m>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle \overline{\langle x,x_m\rangle}\,\langle T^*Tx_n,x_m\rangle\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{n>N}\sum_{m>N}\langle x,x_n\rangle \overline{\langle x,x_m\rangle}\,\langle \lambda_nx_n,x_m\rangle\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{n>N}|\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2 \lambda_n\\ \ \\
&\leq\lambda_N^2\,\sum_{n>N}|\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2 \\ \ \\
&\leq |\lambda_N|^2\,\|x\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: In my own solution can I conclude that because $\|T-S_N \|$ is bounded above the corresponding sum series is convergent and so  $\|T-S_N \| $should converge to 0?

Comment: The series you got in your argument has all terms equal, so it's not finite. More tellingly, your argument doesn't use that  $T $ is compact, nor that the  $x_n $ are eigenvectors of $T^*T $.